# Командный файл, выполняющий действие над всеми архивами внутри рабочей директории

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Я открываю консоль, перехожу в папку D:\work_dir, и тут у меня лежат zip-фрхивы. У меня есть готовое консольное приложение myData.bat , которое выполняет установку данных из zip-архивов. Команда в cmd выглядит так:

```
myData.bat install -a file.zip
```

Здесь для установки я использую **команду install** , а сам архив указываю через **опцию -a**

---

Если надо установить данные из нескольких архивов, то пишу так:

```
myData.bat install -a file1.zip -a file2.zip -a file3.zip
```

---

Теперь надо усложнить немного: теперь у меня в папке D:\work_dir не лежат сразу же zip-aрхивы, а вместо этого находятся директории, а в них поддиректории, сколько именно не известно, разное количество. Но в конечном итоге в поддиректориях в итоге всё равно лежат zip-архивы. И вторая сложность в том, что я не знаю сколько этих архивов будет, может 3 а может 7, или ещё сколько-то. Структура подкаталогов такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, подскажите мне плиз, как написать bat-файл, чтобы там получать все zip-архивы, и применять к ним команду на установку, как показано выше.

Comment: Вы написали " меня есть готовое консольное приложение myData.bat". Покажите код, пожалуйста, а то вопрос выглядит как ТЗ.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте в папке `D:\work_dir` bat-файл и введите туда этот код:

```
@echo off
cd /d "D:\work_dir"
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b /s D:\work_dir\*.zip`) do (
    myData.bat -install -a %%i
)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]